# Photos and music from internal storage got deleted. How to recover them?

Tags: data-recovery

I restarted my LG Android phone and it was supposed to back up my phone's memory – but it deleted my photos and music that was saved to my phone's internal memory.

How do I get my music and photos back?

Comment: I've just added the `data-recovery` tag to your question. Please check [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info) for first aid. Be aware that using the device in its current state lowers your chances of recovery, as data might get overwritten!

Answer (score 1):

I will guide you with the process of getting your pictures back. (For music I would say you always download them again from their original source). Additionally to your device, this procedure will require a Windows or Mac computer/Laptop and an USB cable.

1. I am going to guide you over here with the help of [Dr. Fone for Android by Wondershare](http://www.wondershare.net/data-recovery/android-data-recovery.html?icn=nav). So download and install it over your PC/Laptop.
2. Connect your device with your PC/Laptop with the help of USB cable. Also make sure that USB debugging is enabled over your device. If the USB debugging isn’t available then you can always enable USB debugging under Developers option available under setting. You'll see a notification at the bottom of the screen saying that USB Debugging is being opened in the Dr. Fone Software over your PC/Laptop.
3. Once the connection has been made you will be able to select categories of deleted files i.e Photos, Contacts… etc ! Tap over the category you want to recover! Next Step is to tap over the Scan button for deleted files and follow the options appearing on the screen!

> Note: You'll need to accept the RSA key prompt on your smartphone (check ''Always accept'' to make it easier), making the connection between the two devices secure.
>
> Once it will analyze your phone. There will be reboots, don’t be panic and let the tools do what its doing. Now you’ll get the scan results where you can tap over the check box for the photos you want to recover, so click over it and hit the recover button. And you will get your pictures back!
>
> Hope this time my post helps you in getting your photos back!

Btw: Behind the above link, you can also find a screencast visualizing the process I've explained here.

Comment: Thank for all the guidance over here @Izzy also this tool is available for both Mac/Windows Platform !

Comment: Thanks, Peter – I've just integrated that directly with your answer. I cannot verify it (neither have a broken device, nor a Windows/Mac machine), but it looks pretty good, so I'll upvote it now. You might wish to [edit] the answer once more to include "pricing information" (if any, otherwise it cannot hurt to mention it's free ;)

Comment: @Izzy don't worry whenever you ran onto trouble you can always follow my post over here! :D Also I don't want to add the pricing information as it will look promotional and I am not promoting anything over here rather than what I am trying to do is help ! Free version of the tool is quite good but as like most of the they have locked down some features but for normal usage i think the free version worth ! Also do you have any blog I would like to follow you so I can learn something form you !

Comment: I won't be able to apply your solution – but no worries, I have other means (all my devices are rooted, so I'd just dump the entire partition and "carve" it – details in the [tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info), see the last item). My [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) partially takes care for that. As for the blog: See [IzzyOnDroid](http://android.izzysoft.de/articles.php) and be welcome to follow the same on Twitter :)

Comment: Will this work for internal storage which will connected through MTP and not MSC. I think google ditched MSC from Kitkat.

Comment: @sameer No, worries at all you can use MTP connection type it will work !