# Recovering Erased Audio on Android cellphone

Tags: data-recovery

Thank you in advance, for any help on this.  A friend was raving about 360 Security to install on my droid cellphone, I thought I'd try it, he uninstalled CM Security, and then installed the 360 Security.

WHAM, when I went to my Sound Recorder app, EVERYTHING was gone!! To clarify this was not downloaded music that was missing, this was my music that I would write and record with the Sound Recorder app installed on my cellphone. I tried the link suggested in the post below for a free trial on Dr.Fone the Wondershare.net/data-recovery/android website, and at step four it quit working, it showed a pic of my phone and the laptop communicating via the USB cable, but nothing came up on my laptop screen, nor cellphone, and the next button would not proceed to the next step. Thank you for any suggestions for recovering my erased sound recorder, data. Hoping it's possible!

Comment: Music won't or shouldn't disappear just because you uninstalled an app. But I'd first try this out http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/94119/photos-and-music-from-internal-storage-got-deleted-how-to-recover-them

Comment: Noticed that you haven't edited your question staying what all you tried

Comment: I edited it by adding that I had tried the free trial on the link above, the Dr. Fone Wondershare.net link. I don't know what else to try, the recordings are just gone. I couldn't get further than step 3, on the recovery website for the free trial, and their customer service online was closed. I am open to more suggestions, and Thank anyone for helping me recover my recordings, and Thank you for your suggestions as well

Answer (score 0):

Try taking your sd card out and using recovery software like recuva on your PC... You may also take it to a professional data recovery store, but they typically charge a lot. Data recovery apps for android also exist but I cannot vouch for any... Spend your money carefully!

**[EDIT] POSSIBLE SOLUTION(S):**

---

SOLUTION ONE:

Download **ES file explorer** (free) on your android phone from Google Play. Search both the internal memory and SD card for the missing files... (Tip: There are plenty of tutorials on YouTube)

---

SOLUTION TWO:

Take your SD Card out and connect it to your computer with a SD card reader.
Use a data recovery software:

Windows:

Testdisk (FREE) [http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download ]

Recuva (PAID/FREE) [https://www.piriform.com/recuva ]

GetDataBack (PAID/FREE) [https://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-software.htm ]

---

SOLUTION THREE:

Use data recovery apps on your phone:

Disk Digger (PAID/FREE) [https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.defianttech.diskdigger ]

---

SOLUTION FOUR:

Take your phone to a **Data Recovery Store** (CAN BE EXPENSIVE!)

Comment: Thank you, Rahul. The reviews look pretty good for the data recovery websites, but I had no success trying this morning. I used the free trial, but nothing happened, the free trial said it would show the files that would be recovered, and then when you purchase, you get them back. Nothing came up on my screen. Thank you, yes, I'd like to get this done as least expensive as possible. My last phone was a Blackberry, and my recordings weren't stored on the SD card, but the phone itself. I'm worried that is the way it is on this phone too. I will look in to recuva and hope it's not to complicated

Comment: You're welcome! Recuva can actually be pretty complicated at times... I also recommend looking into GetDataBack, which can be pretty useful. (Hint: there are plenty of cracks for this on file sharing websites, but if anyone asks, I didn't tell you this... ) :-D

Comment: Thank you so much, Rahul. A friend of mine had mentioned a Disk Digger app, do you know anything about this? I don't want to try random things that might make the situation worse. The GetDataBack, I looked it up but found it to be a Window's program....am I able to install this on my Android cellphone? Or would I need to install it on my laptop and transfer it? Please advise, I'm so Thankful, I'm not real tech savvy but would be thrilled if I could recover my data on my own, Thank you again!

Comment: @Celeste No problem! GetDataBack _does_ require a windows PC. You can use an SD card reader to connect it like a thumb drive and then use it. I cannot personally vouch for DiskDiggger but it seems to have received some very good reviews on Google Play. I personally recommend GetDataBack because I have personally tried it, but you need an SD card reader for that (about USD 5). This ofcourse requires the files to have been stored on the SD card. ALSO, The first thing you should try is using ES file explorer to locate the lost files - This may seem silly but can actually be very helpful!

Comment: Thank you, Rahul. I don't know how to go about any of this, but realize I need to just learn. I don't believe the items were stored on my SD card, but again, I wouldn't know. I think I'd like to start with the ES file explorer to locate the lost files, I have Windows 10, on a brand new laptop, and need to go from there, step by step on what to purchase and can start the process. I appreciate your advice, it sounds like the ES file explorer is separate from using the GetDataBack program, any suggestions on the ES file explorer? Do I purchase that program and download it? Thank you again!

Comment: @Celeste Hi again! I think I'll just add it all in my answer... Wait a sec.

Comment: @Celeste There you go!! Anything else??

Comment: Rahul, THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!  I am SO Thankful for the time you took to type all of that out, and provide that information to me! I will start with Step ONE, and have the other steps to guide me through, as needed! Thank you SO very much!! I am going to start on that recovery in the morning! I appreciate all your time in putting this together for me!!! I will let you know how it comes out!! Thanks again and again!!

Comment: @Celeste This is what StackExchange is for! You can help others too by contributing to any community of your choice from the vast network. You're welcome and best of luck!